# I would like to calculate the rotation needed from 2 sets of coordinates knowing where the north is

Tags: c#, math, coordinates

Hi I hope I can make it as clear as possible, but first here is a picture of what I want to calculate:
[image: that]

The camera is at position 0:0 (x and y) the object is at 3:-10.
The camera is facing north at a 1° angle. How can I calculate the angle where the question mark is ?
I am not very good at maths if it is possible to explain in detail what is the procedure it would be great. All this using c#.
Thanks for the help !

Comment: Do you want the difference in *bearing* or angle? They are slightly different (consider when the object reflected through the camera direction - the angle difference would remain the same, but bearing difference would be larger)

Comment: @meowgoesthedog I would like the difference in angle yes. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I come to this result from your description.

```
private double CalcAngle(double x, double y, double extra)
{
  double angle = Math.Atan2(y, x);     // Calculate angle
  angle = angle*180/Math.PI;           // Convert to degrees (from radians)
  angle = 90 - angle;                  // Change from angle with x-as to angle with north        
  angle -= extra;                      // Remove the extra angle
  return angle;
}
```

The use of `Atan2()` instead of `Atan()` will give the result in the correct quadrant.

Answer (score 0):

This is the math behind it:

> arctangent(y/x) - originalAngle

See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1327253/how-do-we-find-out-angle-from-x-y-coordinates) for an explanation of the math.

Comment: `Atan2` might be better in the general case.